# i need to insert into 'Message' column by directly giving value and into 'from_id','to_id' by using select query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
 insert into messages (from_id,to_id,Message) 
 select user_id from user where UserName='winter',
 select user_id from user where UserName='summer',
 **('asdjsadkjsad');**;
```

i need to insert into 'from_id',to_id' columns by getting values from another table so i use select query and at the same time i need to insert into 'Message' column by directly giving value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into messages ( from_id, to_id, Message) 
  select from_id, to_id, 'asdjsadkjsad...' from ( 
    select
      max( case username when 'winter' then user_id end ) as from_id,
      max( case username when 'summer' then user_id end ) as to_id
    from user
  ) as user_ids
```

Let me hope you have *unique* key defined on `username` field. Unless which, you may need more conditions to include to fetch the correct record.

***Refer to***:

- [***MySQL: INSERT ... SELECT Syntax***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html)